# "Reveal spoiler" label blocks mouse interaction after revealing the spoiler

Tags: bug, status-completed, spoilers

In the third spoiler on [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101701/37714) answer, the hyperlink is only partially clickable when hovering over it. The part which is not clickable matches with the dimensions of the "Reveal spoiler" label which is shown on unrevealed spoilers

[image]

Live test  with the example of a hyperlink (line break position depending on the viewport size of your browser):

> foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo [I am a little hyperlink](https://www.wikipedia.org)

---

Credit to [user289905](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353670/reveal-spoiler-label-blocks-mouse-interaction-after-revealing-the-spoiler#comment1182115_353670):

> Currently, the CSS in use is `.s-prose .spoiler.is-visible::after { opacity: 0; }`. Adding [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)` would help. It works in IE11+

Comment: This is not specific to hyperlinks at all. It’s the invisible “Reveal spoiler” label that overlaps the top-right corner. Currently, the CSS in use is `.s-prose .spoiler.is-visible::after { opacity: 0; }`. Adding [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) would help. It works in IE11+.

Comment: @user289905 Ah, thanks! Will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and is live. The fix was exactly as suggested: adding `pointer-events: none` to the `::after` pseudoelement.

Thanks for the report!